# How to set/change LXTerminal font for standard user?

Tags: fonts, lxde, lxterminal

`debian8` is a standard user on my OS (Debian8+LXDE). I follow below steps to change the font on LXterminal.

1. Launch LXterminal after logging in as `debian8`.

   [image]
2. Click Edit > Preferences.

   [image]
3. The default font size is 10 px, which is small.

   [image]
4. I change the font size to 14 px.

   [image]
5. Click OK to apply the changes.

Unfortunately, when the computer is restarted, the font size for user `debian8` reverts to 10px regardless of the font size chosen before restart.

Why is that so?

Is there a script which can be saved on `/home/debian8/.bashrc` to set font size for user `debian8`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check `~/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf`
You can save the right config and overwrite at every boot. But it's better to find out what is overwriting constantly your config files.

Answer (score 1):

```
debian8@hwy:~$ sudo find  /  -name  'lxterminal.conf'
/root/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
/home/debian8/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
/usr/share/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
```

To open every file to get the configure.

```
sudo cat /home/debian8/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
```

Nothing in ,it's blank.

```
sudo cat /usr/share/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
[general]
fontname=Monospace 10
selchars=-A-Za-z0-9,./?%&#:_
scrollback=1000

sudo vim /usr/share/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf
[general]
fontname=Monospace 14
selchars=-A-Za-z0-9,./?%&#:_
scrollback=1000
```

:wq and logout and login in again,problem vanish.